# How can i see log files for a WAF in Azure stored on a storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Whats the best way to see logs for application gateways in Azure, can I use the portal?

I need to see logs for a WAF and the rules triggered. Can someone advise the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really use portal for that, you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) or you can configure your logs to flow to Azure Monitor and view\search them there.

Here's how you would configure logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics